# Real time update with php, node.js, express.js and socket.io

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, angularjs, express

I have created a web app with php as server side and angular as front end. In that application I need realtime update of a grid list, whenever a change is happened in the record. So I have decided to do that part using Node.js+Express.js+Socket.io.

Here I have to notify the change from php to node.js then node.js emits the message regarding changes in the list. After that in my angular side I will use socket.io to get the emitted message.

So whenever i call a url of node.js app from php It will emit the message, but I couldn't able to find any mechanism how to do it in the socket.io examples and tutorials. How I will trigger emit when i call a node url like localhost:3000/articleupdated

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: I have php real time progress bar write with php and `javascript addEventListener`(server side) i can share if you need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you include what you have so far?

It doesn't seem logical to me to have some server code in php, and then have another server running with node, just to use websockets. I've never coded in php, but I would assume that there are libraries similar to socket.io for php (quick google search netted [socketo.me](http://socketo.me/)).

If you must use node.js, you'll need to provide more information about your data implementation. Where is your data stored? How are you monitoring it for updates?

Essentially what I'm guessing needs to happen is you need to open a socket with the server after you load the page, and have the server emit the changes over the socket when they occur. I have a [blog](http://paulgray.net/blog) post talking about some of these concepts (examples with [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/)).